# Asynchronous Programming - It's good But who did that?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Let me start with a famous example of asynchronous programming:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./myhope', function(err, data){
  //Doing something with my hope!
  console.log('Dear world my hope is %s', data);
});
console.log('Help me nurture it');
```

Oops but the output will be asking you to help me nurture my hope before telling you about it. Because it's asynchronous. 
**My question is who in the world is reading the file and storing it in a buffer because node's only thread (it's single threaded) is busy outputting 'Help me nurture it' !** 

Is it something like that node gives an instruction like this 'Dear O/S can you read this file for me and when you have done it just call that callback!. Don't worry my single-threaded loop will handle it'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dear O/S can you read this file for me and when you have done it just
>   call that callback!

That's it, basically. Async IO uses OS kernel facilities to register a callback with an IO. While the IO is running there is no thread in use at all. Not even a background thread.

The callback runs immediately inside of the node process, and queues a work item to the event loop.

Comment: Thanks! for a nice reply! I don't have enough reputation to do a +1 for you. So, just forgive me.
By the way AMD too works on the same philosophy. I mean when requireJs loads AMD modules, she asks some kernels to load them and this don't block. 
But I can't understand why modules are overlapping in this pic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Asynchronous_Module_Definition_overview.png

Comment: Your analogy is correct. The IO in progress is just a data structure all the way down to the hardware interface. The hardware calls back the kernel using an interrupt which is a hardware facility. The same goes for AMD, just the logical call stack is much longer.